# Determine if RPT schedule is runing using command line?

Tags: rpt

Anyone know if its possible to query a Rational Performance Tester 'Controller' from command line and determine if a schedule is executing?
I'm aware that you can query Agents using commands below, but if a RPT schedule fails for some reason the agent process usually continues to be active. Meaning, although a result is returned on Agent, the Controller may not be driving the workload.

```
[root@agent ~]# ps aux | grep [s]cheduleName
root     30000  4.2 11.4 2712004 949872 ?      Sl   13:17  13:46 java
-Drptserver.rootDiscoveryUrl=http://controller.com:7080/deployment/
-Drptagent.agentName=agent.com -Drptagent.engineName=agent.com
-Drptagent.scheduleName=scheduleName 
-Drptagent.rptDeployDir=file:/tmp/rpt/deployment_root/root/A1E0E83B67946D90D6F6E53236393936/ 
-Drptagent.secure=false 
-Drptagent.securePort=7443 
-Drptagent.installBase=/opt/ 
-Xmx2500m -Xmn768m -Xscmx150m -Xgcpolicy:gencon 
-XX:UseThreadPriorities -DrptLocale=en_US
-Drptserver.domoHeavyClass=com.ibm.rational.test.lt.kernel.runner.impl.RPTNextgenRunner
-Drptserver.domoLiteUrl=file:/opt/IBM/SDP/Majordomo/lib/
-Drptserver.domoLiteClass=com.ibm.rational.test.lt.nextgen.Domo 
-cp /opt/IBM/SDP/Majordomo/lib/boot.jar com.ibm.rational.test.lt.boot.DomoBooter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has proven to be most effective:

```
ps aux | grep [s]cheduleName
```